# Wildcard entry for LSApplicationQueriesSchemes in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone

I want to deep-linking (openurl) in my all apps, every app bundle identifier start from com.app.something-something (com.app.*) and list of all apps are coming from server.

So how can I open this app with single entry as wildcard in my LSApplicationQueriesSchemes at Info.plist. Additional to check how many of apps are installed in phone.

Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to use wildcards in LSApplicationQueriesSchemes.

But you can open any link to your other apps without declaring it in LSApplicationQueriesSchemes using the [open](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplication/1648685-open) method, the only point is that you can't guarantee your app will be installed to handle the link.

To check if your other apps are installed you must use [canOpenURL](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplication/1622952-canopenurl) method, but in this case if it is not listed under LSApplicationQueriesSchemes the method will always return false.

What you can do is list all your apps under LSApplicationQueriesSchemes in all your apps and update it regularly when you release new versions, as in the example below:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>com.app.myapp1</string>
    <string>com.app.myapp2</string>
    <string>com.app.myapp3</string>
</array>
```